# VOLTTRON agent subscribe to another agent on pubsub

Tags: python, volttron

I have 2 VOLTTRON agents on a single machine deployment created with the [agent creation wizard](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/stable/developing-volttron/developing-agents/agent-development.html).

I have one agent publishing to the pubsub message bus a string and on the listeragent the string is `Message:'6/8/54'` looks like this:

```
2021-12-26 08:54:33,462 (listeneragent-3.3 22947) __main__ INFO: Peer: pubsub, Sender: platform.checkeragent:, Bus: , Topic: fsm/control/topic, Headers: {'min_compatible_version': '3.0', 'max_compatible_version': ''}, Message:
'6/8/54'
```

Where I am struggling is on a different VOLTTRON agent (`platform.fsmagent`) trying to subscribe to receive this `Message:'6/8/54'` information/data through message bus subscription of the original sender (`platform.checkeragent`). All internal VOLTTRON message bus on a single machine deployment.

What am I doing wrong on the VOLTTRON agent (`platform.fsmagent`) trying to receive the info `Message` by listening to the bus? My on "onstart" looks like this below in the code snip. Am not having any luck trying to subscribe to the topic or the sender.

```
@Core.receiver("onstart")
def onstart(self, sender, **kwargs):

    # subscribe to this sender VOLTTRON agent
    self._create_subscriptions("platform.checkeragent")
```

And my `_create_subscriptions` method looks like this with the `_handle_publish` callback:

```
def _create_subscriptions(self, sender):

    _log.debug(f'[FSM AGENT] -  _create_subscriptions {sender}')
    self.vip.pubsub.subscribe(peer='pubsub',
                            sender=sender,
                            callback=self._handle_publish)
```

And my `_handle_publish` callback looks like this:

```
def _handle_publish(self, peer, sender, bus, topic, headers, message):

    _log.debug(f"[FSM AGENT] - topic_formatted {topic}")
    _log.debug(f"[FSM AGENT] - message {message}")
```

But in the VOLTTRON log these debug messages in the `_handle_publish` callback are not getting printed to the log. Do I need to loop through topics in this callback? No errors its just catching anything which I am hoping to the `Message:'6/8/54'`

When I install the `platform.fsmagent` agent , I see debug statements that the subscriptions seem OK.

```
2021-12-26 08:52:45,177 (fsmagentagent-0.1 59147) __main__ DEBUG: [FSM AGENT] -  _create_subscriptions platform.checkeragent
2021-12-26 08:52:45,178 (fsmagentagent-0.1 59147) __main__ DEBUG: [FSM AGENT] - Onstart FSM Machine SUCCESS!
```

My `vctl status` looks like this:

```
UUID AGENT                 IDENTITY              TAG      STATUS          HEALTH
0 actuatoragent-1.0     platform.actuator     actuator running [52337] GOOD
c bacnet_proxyagent-0.5 platform.bacnet_proxy proxy    running [23089] GOOD
1 checkeragentagent-0.1 platform.checkeragent checker  running [57410] GOOD
f fsmagentagent-0.1     platform.fsmagent     fsm      running [59147]
8 listeneragent-3.3     listeneragent-3.3_1   listener running [22947] GOOD
```

Answer (score 0):

When subscribing to the message bus you subscribe to a topic prefix. Based on the listener agent output you posted, the sender (platform.checkeragent agent) is publishing to the Topic "fsm/control/topic". To subscribe to that specific topic you should modify your subscribe statement in platform.fsmagent to

```
self.vip.pubsub.subscribe(peer='pubsub',
                           prefix='fsm/control/topic',
                           callback=cb)
```

you can also provide a topic prefix such as 'fsm' or 'fsm/control' to receive messages posted to all subtopics.

To subscribe you can also use the decorator
`@PubSub.subscribe('pubsub', 'fsm/control/topic')` on top of the _handle_publish method. if you leave the prefix empty then it subscribes to all topics. This is what the Listener agent does.